# Canvas toDataURL() returns blank image

Tags: javascript, firefox, canvas, webgl, todataurl

I'm using [glfx.js](http://evanw.github.io/glfx.js/) to edit my image but when I'm trying to get that image's data using the `toDataURL()` function I get a blank image (width the same size as the original image).

The strange thing is that in Chrome the script works perfect.

What I want to mention is that the image is loaded in `canvas` using the onload event:

```
           img.onload = function(){

                try {
                    canvas = fx.canvas();
                } catch (e) {
                    alert(e);
                    return;
                }

                // convert the image to a texture
                texture = canvas.texture(img);

                // draw and update canvas
                canvas.draw(texture).update();

                // replace the image with the canvas
                img.parentNode.insertBefore(canvas, img);
                img.parentNode.removeChild(img);

            }
```

Also my image's path is on the same domain;

The problem (in Firefox) is when i hit the save button. Chrome returns the expected result but Firefox return this:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA7YAAAIWCAYAAABjkRHCAAAHxklEQVR4nO3BMQEAAADCoPVPbQZ/oAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
... [ lots of A s ] ... 
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACAzwD6aAABkwvPRgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==
```

What could cause this result and how can I fix it?

Comment: Is the Image you are editing on the same domain? Just to exclude the obvious.

Comment: Yes it is. I'll edit my post to mention that! There is a problem in Firefox (and not in chrome) with images that are not on the same domain?

Comment: Seem to be an async operation taking place somewhere. If the image is not loaded when toDataURL() is invoked the canvas would be blank.

Comment: The image is loaded on the canvas and I can see  and edit it.The problem is that the toDataURL is not getting the right information from canvas.

Comment: As an extra thing to check, if the width or height of the canvas is 0, as per the documentation, `getDataURL()` returns `"data:," `. I was getting this after (incorrectly) setting the size of the canvas to 0.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Most likely there's some async event between the time you draw to the canvas and the time you call `toDataURL`. By default the canvas is cleared after every composite. Either prevent the canvas from being cleared by creating the WebGL context with `preserveDrawingBuffer: true` as in

```
var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl", {preserveDrawingBuffer: true});
```

or make sure toDataURL is called before exiting whatever event you're using to render.  For example if you do this

```
function render() {
  drawScene(); 
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
render();
```

And somewhere else do this

```
someElement.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var data = someCanvas.toDataURL();
}, false);
```

Those 2 events, the `animation frame`, and the `click` are not in sync and the canvas may be cleared between calling them. Note: The canvas won't appear cleared as it's double buffered but the buffer toDataURL and other commands that effect that buffer are looking at is cleared.

The solution is either use `preserveDrawingBuffer` or make your call to `toDataURL` inside the same event as rendering. For example

```
var captureFrame = false;

function render() {
  drawScene(); 

  if (captureFrame) {
    captureFrame = false;
    var data = someCanvas.toDataURL();
    ...
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
render();

someElement.addEventListener('click', function() {
  captureFrame = true;
}, false);
```

What's the point of `preserveDrawingBuffer: false` which is the default? It can be significantly faster, especially on mobile to not have to preserve the drawing buffer. Another way to look at it is the browser needs 2 copies of your canvas. The one you're drawing to and the one it's displaying. It has 2 ways to deal with these 2 buffers. (A) double buffer. Let you draw to one, display the other, swap the buffers when you're done rendering which is inferred from exiting any event that issued draw commands (B) Copy the contents of the buffer you're drawing to do the buffer that's being displayed. Swapping is much faster than copying. So, swapping is the default. It's up to the browser what actually happens. The only requirement is that if `preserveDrawingBuffer` is `false` that the drawing buffer get cleared after a composite (which is yet another async event and therefore unpredictable) if `preserveDrawingBuffer` is `true` then it must copy so that the drawingbuffer's contents is preserved.

Note that once a canvas has a context it will always have the same context. So in other words let's say you change the code that initializes the WebGL context but you still want to set `preserveDrawingBuffer: true`

There are at least 2 ways.

#### find the canvas first, get a context on it

since the code later will end up with the same context.

```
<script>
document.querySelector('#somecanvasid').getContext(
    'webgl', {preserveDrawingBuffer: true});
</script>
<script src="script/that/will/use/somecanvasid.js"></script>
```

Because you've already created a context for that canvas whatever script comes after will get the same context.

#### augment `getContext`

```
<script>
HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext = function(origFn) {
  return function(type, attributes) {
    if (type === 'webgl') {
      attributes = Object.assign({}, attributes, {
        preserveDrawingBuffer: true,
      });
    }
    return origFn.call(this, type, attributes);
  };
}(HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext);
</script>
<script src="script/that/will/use/webgl.js"></script>
```

In this case any webgl context created after augmenting the `getContext` will  have `preserveDrawingBuffer` set to true.

Comment: Because I'm using glfx.js library I don't have direct access to the canvas and render methods. I called the toDataURL function event with a timeout of 5 sec and it didn't work. I don't think is something async here... Can it be something else?

Comment: Calling toDataURL with an timeout of 5 sec IS AN ASYNC EVENT. You're in JavaScript. You have the source to glfx.js. Change it.

Comment: I managed to solve the issue by updating the canvas element with a glfx function (`update()`). Yet I don't know why this issue was only in FF and not in Chrome. Thank you!

Comment: It's FF only because the spec is ambiguous here. The WebGL spec says effectively, if a draw command is issued to the WebGL context, the next time the webpage is composited with the page the canvas's drawing buffer will be cleared. When compositing happens is asynchronous. In other words you don't know when it will happen and what events will happen between the time you draw something and the time composite happens and the buffer gets cleared. That means it's different on every browser. In Chrome's case you're getting the canvas before it's cleared, in FF after it's cleared.

Comment: This explains it. Thank you!

Comment: In WebGL version I do the following when I create the canvas (I am also using a stencil buffer): `gl = canvas.getContext("webgl", {stencil : true, preserveDrawingBuffer : true});`