# requestAnimationFrame , readpixel and implicit clear

Tags: javascript, webgl

I do not understand why I lose readpixel values ​​inside the requestanimationframe loop?

```
var pixels = new Uint8Array(12*12*4); 

gl.clearColor(0.5, 0.8, 0.0, 1.0);
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
gl.readPixels(0, 0, 12, 12, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
console.log(pixels[0]);  //OK 128 !
anim();


function anim() {

  var pixels2 = new Uint8Array(12*12*4); 

  gl.readPixels(0, 0, 12, 12, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels2);
  console.log(pixels2[0]); // STRANGE : 0 ????
  requestAnimationFrame(anim);
}
```

obviously, if I add

```
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

inside the anim() {...} , the value is 128. But without that gl.clear, why there is a black clear ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because by default WebGL clears the drawing buffer after every composite operation. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/26790802/128511

If you don't want WebGL to clear the drawing buffer you need to pass in `preserveDrawingBuffer: true` to `getContext`

```js
const gl = document.querySelector('canvas')
  .getContext('webgl', {preserveDrawingBuffer: true});
var pixels = new Uint8Array(12*12*4); 

gl.clearColor(0.5, 0.8, 0.0, 1.0);
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
gl.readPixels(0, 0, 12, 12, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
console.log(pixels[0]);  //OK 128 !
anim();


function anim() {

  var pixels2 = new Uint8Array(12*12*4); 

  gl.readPixels(0, 0, 12, 12, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels2);
  console.log(pixels2[0]); // STRANGE : 0 ????
  requestAnimationFrame(anim);
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: oh...ok ! i was searching for requestanimationframe specification. And that is a webgl behaviour. thanks !