WebGL's "drawArrays" erases previous draws
I have this function which draws a rectangle of dimension rect with a texture on a gl context:
const drawRect = (
        gl: WebGL2RenderingContext,
        texture: WebGLTexture,
        rect: [number, number, number, number]
    ) =>
    {
        const buffer = createRectVertexBuffer(gl)(rect);
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);

        const program = createMapTileProgram(gl);
        gl.useProgram(program);

        const positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'position');
        const texcoordLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'texcoord');
        const textureLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'u_texture');

        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 16, 0);

        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(texcoordLocation);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(texcoordLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 16, 8);

        gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        gl.uniform1i(textureLocation, 0);

        gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4); // <-- this line here remove previous draws
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
    }

The function works, but every time I call it, previous draws (which were all also made using this function) disappear, and I can see them flickering in and out of the canvas in sequence.
I initialize WebGL like this:
const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl2')!;
gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);
// The lines bellow were attempts to fix the issue
gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
gl.blendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
gl.disable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

I'm on Firefox. I've noticed that the issue doesn't happens if the window is hidden (i.e. if I'm on another tab).
What's going on?

Look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26783586/canvas-todataurl-returns-blank-image/26790802#26790802
